# How do I save Facebook App Settings - they keep disappearing

Tags: api, facebook

Please excuse me if this has already been answered. I have looked at a number of similar questions, but they all say the problem has been resolved.

I created a Facebook app, but when using the API, it complains that I need to add a domain to the app domains. I then open up the Facebook app and in the Basic settings, I add the domain and save the changes. There are no errors visible or when I look in the Developer Console.

However, when I go navigate off the Basic settings and back onto it, all the changes are gone.

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong. It is hard to believe that something this basic isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

User error. Everything works as expected. Went through app setup very slowly and finally did it correctly.